# Track all of one dir but only specific files in another

Tags: git, glob, gitignore

I have a fresh `git init --shared` which results in:

> .git
> /dir1
> /dir2
> .gitignore

I want to track everything inside of `dir1` and only `.conf` files inside of `dir2`.

So far I have this in my gitignore but it's not working as expected; `dir2` remains totally untracked.

```
# Track the root
!/

# Omit every item under the root
/*

# Track dir1 under the root
!/dir1/

# Track .conf files anywhere
!*.conf

# Track .gitignore under the root
!.gitignore
```

Output of `git status`:

```
.gitignore
dir1/
```